# StringWrite built using a JAXB Marshaller shows "&lt;" rather than "<" when viewed using POSTMAN

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, apache-axis, unmarshalling

I'm building a ***web service*** and ***application project***. Service stores the data within a local XML file containing bookInfo. Web service has a method to view all the booksInfo stored inside this XML file. Therefore, to read the XML, I'm using ***JAXB*** and unmarshalling it to POJO

## UnMarshalling

```
AllItems items = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AllItems.class);
        Unmarshaller unMarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("items.xml"));
        items = (AllItems) unMarshaller.unmarshal(fileReader);

//items here is an object of the supposed to be the root element
```

## Marshalling

After this I've marshalled this to StringWrite with following code:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();    
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(items, stringWriter);
} 
catch (JAXBException | FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

When I **view the output on the console**, everything **looks pretty**. If, I view the output using the endpoint address on a web browser, it still looks pretty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<allItems>
<items>
    <saleInfo>
        <country>AU</country>
        <saleability>FOR_SALE</saleability>
    </saleInfo>
    <status>back order</status>
    <volumeInfo>
        <authors>Liz Ellis</authors>
        <industryIdentifiers>
            <identifier>9781760780364</identifier>
            <type>ISBN_13</type>
        </industryIdentifiers>
        <industryIdentifiers>
            <identifier>1760780367</identifier>
            <type>ISBN_10</type>
        </industryIdentifiers>
        <publishedDate>2018-04-24</publishedDate>
        <publisher>Macmillan Publishers Aus.</publisher>
        <title>If At First You Don't Conceive</title>
    </volumeInfo>
</items>
```

But **problem** starts when I use **POSTMAN** or try to view it using the **web server console**.

Not desired output **how to make application receive "<" instead of &alt;"**

```
    &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
&lt;allItems>
    &lt;items>
        &lt;saleInfo>
            &lt;country>AU&lt;/country>
            &lt;saleability>FOR_SALE&lt;/saleability>
        &lt;/saleInfo>
        &lt;status>back order&lt;/status>
        &lt;volumeInfo>
            &lt;authors>Liz Ellis&lt;/authors>
            &lt;industryIdentifiers>
                &lt;identifier>9781760780364&lt;/identifier>
                &lt;type>ISBN_13&lt;/type>
            &lt;/industryIdentifiers>
            &lt;industryIdentifiers>
                &lt;identifier>1760780367&lt;/identifier>
                &lt;type>ISBN_10&lt;/type>
            &lt;/industryIdentifiers>
            &lt;publishedDate>2018-04-24&lt;/publishedDate>
            &lt;publisher>Macmillan Publishers Aus.&lt;/publisher>
            &lt;title>If At First You Don't Conceive&lt;/title>
        &lt;/volumeInfo>
    &lt;/items>
&lt;/allItems>
```

Comment: Probably some problem with Postman. JAXB/your web service seem to output it correctly.

Comment: @lexicore that’s what I thought initially, but after using local host admin panel and requesting the service to return the same XML output, it returned that same “&lt;”  output. But if I try to send a request to the same endpoint outside of the admin panel, it just works.

Comment: Local host admin might be wrong, too. They probably blindly escape everything when displaying response in the HTML page. Try to test it with bare `curl`. You problem seems to be unrelated to your web service but rather to tools you use to view results (Postman/local host admin panel).

Comment: @lexicore sadly `curl` returs the `bad output` as well :(